# uploading files - how to store file in non public folder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with uploading files. I followed these instructions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html and everything is working fine, but I want to save uploaded files in a folder that is not public and with random name and then send it to the browser in original name. 
I know how to put file in non public folder with random name and how to save original name to database, but what should I do next for getting this file content and send it to browser with original name? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the hidden path in the database, then just read it in your php script that is public available and send your file to a user, if you don't how to send files in php, you can find it out [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+send+file).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know how to send file in plain PHP script. I thought, maybe in symfony is some kind of tools to do that :)

Comment: Nope, there's only File class that is just \SplFileInfo and Response class that you can use to set proper headers. Let's see if someone has an answer with good code example.